# Can't run vmware on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, vmware-workstation

i have some unknow error when i try run vmware

the fitst when i didn't use admin right open vmware will see this error

`vmware authorization service is not running`

but when i use admnin run vmware

it didn't show any message and still can't work

[image]

[image]

anyone know how can i fix this error, or where can i found more message for try find what is worng?

VMware workstation 12.1.1

windows 10

cpu i7

my system didn't install hype-v

C:\Windows\Temp\vmware-SYSTEM

pasted.co/5837e89d

C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\vmware-USER

pasted.co/cb1e874d

Comment: What version of VMWare?

Comment: VMware workstation 12.1.1

Comment: You have tried, removing VMWare Workstation, then installing it again?

Comment: i try unstall and full delete vmware data and folder, also try open it at safe mode too

Comment: Which i7? You need a CPU that supports IOMMU, called VT-d on Intel systems. Google search "VT-d [cpu model]" to find out. Also be sure that you have enough free disk space and RAM to run another OS.

Comment: i7-6700 + GA-Z170-HD3 + 24G RAM + enough free disk space

Answer (score 0):

Please run " systeminfo.exe" and ensure the virtualization enabled in firmware is listed and yes.
[image]

Comment: all field is yes

Answer (score 0):

...

i found what is wrong at my pc

my comodo block all incoming [0-1023] port

vmware-authd.exe use 902 & 912

so that is why my vmware authorization service is running

, but it never can see is runing

thx everyone who trying help find what is wrong

Comment: Please use the **Post Your Answer** button only for actual answers. You should edit your original post to add additional information.